# How can I specify dependencies between CARs in WSO2 Carbon product?

Tags: wso2

We are planning to deploy 4 CARs into a single instance of WSO2 Governance Registry. CAR #1 depends on the WSDL and XSD packaged in CAR #4. If we simply drop all 4 CARs into deployment directory of the Carbon product, the system won't be able to deploy CAR #1 as WSDL validation will fail. The same issue applies to ESB.

Is there a way to specify cross-CAR dependencies in Carbon framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAR file are supposed to be self contained Artifacts. Thus all the CAR file should contain all the artifacts within itself. Therefore we do not have a concept of cross dependencies between CAR files. So there is no mechanism to define such dependencies in between CAR files.

Only possible solution is to deploy the dependent CAR files after deploying the independent CAR files.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana